# Why does my texture only attaches to a certain part of the model? And how can I fix it?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, 3d-view

I'm new to Blender, I use the 4.0.2 version and tried applying a UV Map to design my model, but my texture is stuck in one place. I tried reapplying the UV Map all over the model, removing it, double-checking if the image is attached to the color, merging the objects, marking seams, and deleting textures and images on the model. I cannot fix the issue, though. Any help on this is greatly appreciated!

[image: Blender 4.0.2]

Texture:

[image: Texture]

UV Map:

[image: UVMap]

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed the texture and the UV map in your question. Or even upload the file with the packed texture here: https://blend-exchange.com and follow the instructions to edit it into your question.

Comment: The model has 2 material slots. The first is empty, the second is assigned the red material. The head parts have slot 2 assigned and are red, while the rest of the model has slot 1 assigned and is white. If you only want to use one material for the entire model, delete material slot 1 (it is the one above the purple entry in the screenshot).

Comment: @Blunder Thank you, the first slot had nothing but a + sign, I wasn't able to delete it but I tried adding the red material to it using the icon beside it, and the entire form is now the red color! I'm unable to draw with the texture paint though, but I believe I'll make it a separate question. Cheers!